# Why isn't SQL Server using my clustered index and doing a non-clustered index scan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a `patient` table with a few columns, and a clustered index on column `ID` and a non-clustered index on column `birth`.

```
create clustered index CI_patient on dbo.patient (ID)
create nonclustered index NCI_patient on dbo.patient (birth)
```

Here are my queries:

```
select * from patient 

select ID from patient

select birth from patient
```

Looking at the execution plan, the first query is 'clustered index scan' (which is understandable because the table is a clustered table), the third one is 'index scan nonclustered' (which is also understandable because this column has a nonclustered index)

My question is why the second one is 'index scan nonclustered'? This column suppose to have a clustered index, in this sense, should that be clustered index scan? Any thoughts on this?

[image: query]

Comment: How large is the table?  The query plans on small tables don't mean much.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is a pretty small table, or a test table. I created it to practice sql index.

Comment: A non-clustered index also contains the clustered index key as [the row locater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15). This is ID - so it is more efficient to scan that index. Change the clustered index to something else and you will likely see that plan change to the clustered index.

Comment: @SMor, would you please further explain why if the column is ID it would more efficient to be non-clustered index scan? Thanks!

Comment: @Kay, the leaf nodes of the non-clustered index contain only birth(the key column) and id (row locator) as @SMor mentioned. The leaf nodes of the clustered index contain all columns in the table. Although both contain the requested `id` column, the optimizer chose the non-clustered index because is faster to scan the smaller of the 2 indexes. Full scans (e.g. no WHERE clause) typically use the narrowest index with all the columns needed by the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, your second query wants to get all `ID` values from the table (no `WHERE` clause or anything).

SQL Server can do this two ways:

- clustered index scan - basically a full table scan to read all the data from all rows, and extract the `ID` from each row - would work, but it loads **the WHOLE table**, one by one
- do a scan across the non-clustered index, because each non-clustered index **also** includes the clustering column(s) on its leaf level. Since this is a index that is much **smaller** than the full table, to do this, SQL Server will need to load **fewer data pages** and thus can provide the answer - all `ID` values from all rows - faster than when doing a full table scan (clustered index scan)

The cost-based optimizer in SQL Server just picks the **more efficient** route to get the answer to the question you've asked with your second query.